# Pass custom class data between view controllers in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, class, swift, viewcontroller

I have two view controllers one that contains a tableview and another that contains the page to show following selection of a particular row.

At the start of my viewController i have my Class variable instantiated

```
var myTableViewItem = Item()
```

I have got the selected row information from the data array:

...

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
         myTableViewItem = pList[indexPath.row]
         println("\(itemViewItem.getItemName())")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("itemSelect", sender: myTableViewItem)
}



override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "itemSelect" {
        let nController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
        let newController = nController.viewControllers[0] as ItemDetailViewController
        println("\(myTableViewItem.getItemValue())") //Statement correctly prints item parameter.
        newController.itsItem = myTableViewItem as Item
    }
}
```

and have a parameter in the destination view controller (newController) with an optional class reference

```
var thisItem: Item!
```

however whenever i attempt to access any class data in the subsequent view controller it only ever holds default initialiser values. Instead of those passed from the sending object

The sending object is definitely fully populated with non-default values (as verified with console print statements). i can't figure out why this is happening when i attempt to assign the data.

Ive searched online and looked at other posts for two days now to no avail!

Comment: Post code from `ItemDetailViewController`. It is probably setting its own value somewhere after initialization. The most likely culprit is `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`

Comment: Agreed. It is possible that there is a method overwriting it at some point, probably in one of the appear methods. I can't see a reason you'd be addressing the wrong instance.

Comment: Is there a typo here?  The parameter on your `ItemDetailViewController` is called `thisItem`, but in your code above you are passing `myTableViewItem` to something called `itsItem`

Comment: There is a typo but thats only as i was making the names generic to put online. but its the same parameter thisItem is what i was referring to when i wrote newController.itsItem .. The item being used in the second controller

Answer (score 0):

**Changed answer based on comments below**:

If I understand correctly,

make the property an optional

```
var  thisItem: Item?
```

Then in viewDidLoad method check if it is nil to set the default value, it will likely have a value here if you are setting it previously:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
if thisItem! == nil{
 thisItem = theDefaultValue
}
```

....

**Old Answer:**
If you can't figure out where the value is being changed, I would add a setter/getter with a breakpoint as such

```
var _thisItem: Item?
var  thisItem: Item? {
  get {
    return _thisItem;
  }

  set {
    _thisItem = newValue;
    println("value was changed to \(newValue)");//add a breakpoint here and check trace.
  }
}
```

Comment: Im sure the problem is when I'm trying doing:

newController.itsItem = myTableViewItem as Item

Although I'm referring to itsItem which has been declared as:

var thisItem: Item!

its creating a new object and the initialiser parameters in the init method of the class is whats populating each variable in the object instead of copying the previous ones. Trouble is i don't see how i can get around that because each of the parameters in the class needs to be explicitly defined in the initialiser method

Comment: If i understand correctly..  Then I would
1) change it to an optional with a ? at the end (the value then starts as nil)

set in initMethod  as follows

if  thisItem! == nil{
    thisItem = your default value;
}

Comment: (for ease of formatting i added my comment as an additional answer)

Comment: I'd rather use `didSet`. Then only one property is needed, and no `get` is required.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input. I've narrowed the problem down to a class initialisation issue.

i modified the code to include an optional variable in the second view controller:

```
var: tester:string!
```

and included an additional line in the first VC:

```
var test = itemViewItem.itemName
newController.tester = test
```

when the second view controller loads i am able to print out the name to the console from viewDidLoad(). therefore the problem is that when my custom class is assigned a value in the new VC. It is not able to take the value of given to it for some reason.

oddly though if i include the same object initialiser that i had in the second controller within the first:

```
var itemTest: Item!

itemTest = itemViewItem

println(itemTest.itemName)
println(itemViewItem.itemName)
```

the two are equivalent. However the value that in the second view controller is 'nil' the first time around. however if i press the back button and then return to the view controller the second/third/forth.. times it will work as expected from then on with whatever row (item) initiates the segue. Leading me to believe its something to do with passing information and class implementation.